# Database driven windows desktop application with embedded database on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, embedded-database, visual-studio-2015

1. I have to build a Windows Desktop application that stores data and is able to manipulate data but the problem is, I cannot decide which database to use?
2. I need the app to be standalone so that minimum to no other software needs to be installed on the client PC( windows vista to 10 ).
3. I need the app to be able to export the data and maybe connect the database to the cloud.
4. I'm using C# as language and WPF as user interface platform.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365171/which-database-to-use-for-standalone-application-winforms) question it almost covers my requirements.

But as the **Sql Compact Edition** is depreciated in after 2013 visual studio editions I'm not sure what to use.

I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11481705/1729636) answer, it covers the same things this but I'm not sure what does that mean, does it mean if I use **Microsoft SQL Server** as database and Embed the **MS SQL Server Express** ( latest, database only ) with my application *I will not need to setup a server explicitly.*

And if I do follow this practice what are the other things that I might need to consider before making this choice.

And to be Clear I'm using **Visual Studio 2015 Community** and I have been using **Service Based Database** that creates a **.mdf** file and I like that approach and the main focus of me asking this question is that, if I continue with the same approach ( **Service Based Database** ) and embed **MS SQL Server Express (**database only ) with my application, will I be ok with point 1,2,3,4 above ?

Please provide any insights into this matter.

I cannot make a decision without knowing that someone has done it and it works.

Comment: What you're currently using is a LocalDB instance, which *still* need an [installation](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/b/weblog/archive/2014/01/02/what-is-localdb). Have you considered SQLite?

Comment: @martheen I was thinking of using the tools shipped with visual studio so I didn't consider SQLite, and will I be fine if I follow the approach described above?

Comment: Your current approach still require the installation of SQL Server Express (albeit only the minimal LocalDB version, without server setting required). No current solution from Microsoft support true embedded DB. SQL CE can be supported via add on on VS 2015 though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few tips to ensure that you're future-proof:

1. Do not interact with the database from your code directly. Set up contracts (Interfaces) and do all implementation in a separate DLL. IF you need to move from a local db to a cloud db, you can then simply re-implement the same interface for the cloud database and your code will run as before
2. With the method in (1) you're basically also quite free to use a radically different type of data store, i.e. one of the many NoSQL databases out there.

I usually call my database contracts for XXXRepository or XXXStore, example:

```
public interface IProductStore
{
    IEnumerable<Product> All { get; }

    IEnumerable<Product> OutOfStock { get; }

    Product GetById(Guid Id);
}
```

I can implement this ProductStore contract in a separate DLL that only deals with for example SQLite that has already been mentioned here, or anything else. You then either use a factory or IoC Container to do the mapping between the interface and implementation:

```
var productsStore = DependencyResolver.Resolve<IProductStore>();

foreach(var product in productsStore.OutOfStock)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine($"Need to refill: {product.Name}");
}
```

This leaves you VERY free to try out a ton of different databases that can fit your need, and you only need to change the configuration to use a different type of database

Comment: @pedro-g-dias It's a great answer, it took me some time to understand your logic but I'm a newbie who just needs to get the job done easily but I'll follow your approach it seems to me the right choice and I've used this logic in Django so I think it's for the best